# What does nf_conntrack.acct really do?

Tags: linux, iptables, kernel, nf-conntrack

I've found the kernel parameter `nf_conntrack.acct` interesting, in that the kernel documentation merely says "Enable connection tracking flow accounting".
I've appended this to grub and rebooted and I haven't found any difference. For example, what it has to do with the `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

From [iptables-extensions(8)](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html):

> The "net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct" sysctl flag controls whether new 
>   connections will be byte/packet counted. Existing connection flows will
>   not be gaining/losing a/the accounting structure when be sysctl flag is flipped.

This accounting information can then be used to create rules for the `connbytes` netfilter module. Note that setting this option does not require a reboot, this can be enabled at runtime (for new connections only):

> `sudo sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1`

When enabled, `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` will carry information about packet count and size:

```
 $ grep dport=1234 /proc/net/nf_conntrack
 ipv4     [...] sport=58730 dport=1234 packets=324 bytes=480352 [...]
```